# let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes such that $p < q$, where $N = p q$. Does $N$ contain any information about $q-p$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes such that $p < q$, where $N = p q$.

1. Does $N$ contain any information about $q-p$?
2. Is it possible to know exactly or estimate the difference between $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *information* here. Strictly speaking $N$ determines $p$ and $q$ uniquely (by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic), and therefore knowing $N$ in principle reveals both $p$ and $q$. The catch is that finding $p$ and $q$ (given $N$) is comptutationally extremely taxing, and for large enough $N$ currently infeasible. The security of RSA public key cryptosystem relies on this infeasibility. So A) in theory $N$ contains this information, but B) no method of quickly computing it (with traditional computing models) is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer: If you know $q-p$ exactly, then you can get $p$ and $q$.

**Proof.** If you knew $q-p$ then you'd know $(q-p)^2=p^2-2pq+q^2$. Adding $4N=4pq$ gives you $(p+q)^2$, which we can square root to get $s=p+q$. From here,

$$p,q=\frac{s\pm\sqrt{s^2-4N}}{2}$$

by the quadratic formula.

---

In a similar vein, if we were able to estimate $q-p$ very well, we'd be able to just try all the values around it quite quickly to see if they yielded a valid factorization. So, we can't know it *too* well.

Comment: so i don't get any information at all about q-p just by looking at N?

Comment: you get all the information about $q-p$ only if you factorize N. You get some information about $p+q$ if you write $(p+q)> 2sqrt(N)$